# Vaadin 14 application fails to load resource and displays a blank page

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am working on upgrading a Vaadin 8 application to Vaadin 14. When I run the application using embedded Jetty and open it in Google Chrome, I get a blank white screen.

In Chrome DevTools, I see the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for `http://localhost:31415/VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js`.

It was suggested to me in a previous question of mine that this issue might be related to the `@PWA` annotation, but my application does not use this annotation. I tried adding the annotation to the parent layout, but this did not help.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue or how to solve it?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the server log as it starts?

Comment: @MarcusHellberg No, there are no errors in the server log.

Comment: Have you looked at this example: https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin14-embedded-jetty

Comment: The file `VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js` is in the `flow-client.jar` so it would sound like the embedded jetty is not serving the client file from the jar like it should as the BootstrapHandler does find the `compile.properties` from the same place.